# javascript math function: Right now it forms a circle, I need to make a semi-circle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

These are the codes used, It forms a complete circle as of now, but I need a semi circle. The changes have to be made to the JS function but I added the html and CSS for reference.

For help can someone also tell me how to make it an ellipse?
JS:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');
for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*
  (1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*
   (1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 100%;
  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
   opacity: 1;

   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
 }

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  min-width: 1em;

  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<nav class="circular-menu">

<div class="circle">
  <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x">*</a>
</div>

<a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
```

Comment: So change the code to only form a half circle.

Comment: use only half the code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX You actually got 3 votes for that comment.. wow

Comment: sometimes humour is appreciated :p (I don't understand it either :p )

Comment: I think it's the opposite since I doubled the code to get half the circle :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to understand if you broke out the math

```
const centerX = 50;
const centerY = 50;
const radius = 35;

var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');
for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {

  const angle = -0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI;

  items[i].style.left = (centerX - radius * Math.cos(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  items[i].style.top = (centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}
```

That should make it clearer you need to change `angle`

First it's hard to see l vs i so

```
for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {

  const angle = -0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / len) * i * Math.PI;
```

Then let's break out the math a little
Let's rework angle to make it clearer

```
  const zeroToOne = i / len;  // goes from zero to one
  const angleOffset = -0.5 * Math.PI;
  const angle = angleOffset - 2 * zeroToOne * Math.PI;
```

lerping is easier with values that go from 0 to 1. Once we have a value that goes from zero to one we can easily make a function that converts that to any range

```
  function lerp(start, end, zeroToOne) {
     return start + (end - start) * zeroToOne;
  }
```

so

```
  const angleOffset = -0.5 * Math.PI;
  const startAngle = angleOffset;
  const endAngle = angleOffset - 2 * Math.PI;

  const zeroToOne = i / len;  // goes from zero to one
  const angle = lerp(startAngle, endAngle, zeroToOne);
```

Now you are free to change `startAngle` and `endAngle` to anything you like.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

const centerX = 50;
const centerY = 50;
const radius = 35;
let startAngle = 0;
let endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;

function render() {
  for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    const zeroToOne = i / len;  // goes from zero to one
    const angle = lerp(startAngle, endAngle, zeroToOne);
  
    items[i].style.left = (centerX - radius * Math.cos(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
    items[i].style.top = (centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  }
}
render();

function lerp(start, end, zeroToOne) {
   return start + (end - start) * zeroToOne;
}

document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const zeroToOne = e.target.value / e.target.max;
  startAngle = lerp(0, Math.PI * 2, zeroToOne);
  render();
});

document.querySelector('#end').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const zeroToOne = e.target.value / e.target.max;
  endAngle = lerp(0, Math.PI * 2, zeroToOne);
  render();
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 100%;
  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
   opacity: 1;

   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
 }

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  min-width: 1em;

  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<label>start:</label><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="start">
<label>end:</label><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" id="end">
<nav class="circular-menu">

<div class="circle">
  <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x">*</a>
</div>

<a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
```

as for making an ellipse, now that we've broken it out the math it should be clearer. This

```
const radius = 35;

items[i].style.left = (centerX - radius * Math.cos(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
items[i].style.top = (centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
```

becomes this

```
const radiusX = 75;
const radiusY = 15;

items[i].style.left = (centerX - radiusX * Math.cos(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
items[i].style.top = (centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
```

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

const centerX = 80;
const centerY = 50;
const radiusX = 75;
const radiusY = 15;
let startAngle = 0;
let endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;

function render() {
  for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    const zeroToOne = i / len;  // goes from zero to one
    const angle = lerp(startAngle, endAngle, zeroToOne);
  
    items[i].style.left = (centerX - radiusX * Math.cos(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
    items[i].style.top = (centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(angle)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  }
}
render();

function lerp(start, end, zeroToOne) {
   return start + (end - start) * zeroToOne;
}

document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const zeroToOne = e.target.value / e.target.max;
  startAngle = lerp(0, Math.PI * 2, zeroToOne);
  render();
});

document.querySelector('#end').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const zeroToOne = e.target.value / e.target.max;
  endAngle = lerp(0, Math.PI * 2, zeroToOne);
  render();
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 100%;
  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
   opacity: 1;

   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
 }

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  min-width: 1em;

  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<label>start:</label><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="start">
<label>end:</label><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" id="end">
<nav class="circular-menu">

<div class="circle">
  <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x">*</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x">*</a>
</div>

<a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
```

Comment: This was really hard to understand considering I am bad at maths.. But mow that I got it.. thanks a lot.. I modified the code on my own now!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 2 from 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI in both assignments.
Right now your code relies on I incrementing to meet L, hence causing the value of 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI to increase by 2Pi, resulting in a circle.

If we hobble its increasing ability by half, it will only make a half circle.
Maybe I'm wrong, haven't tried it :P

Comment: Can you also tell me how to make it an ellipse?